# How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-3.0

json serializer settings for legacy asp.net core applications were set by adding `AddMvc().AddJsonOptions()`, but I don't use `AddMvc()` in `asp.net core 3`. So how can I set global json serialization settings?

Comment: If you don't use `AddMvc`, what _do_ you use? Are you using e.g. `AddControllers` or are you just not using MVC at all?

Comment: @KirkLarkin i use default way of building asp.net core 3 app - `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers() })` and `services.AddControllers();`

Comment: Alright, so I guess you're using `AddControllers` in `ConfigureServices`, right?

Comment: @KirkLarkin, yeah, right

Answer (score 111, accepted):

`AddMvc` returns an [`IMvcBuilder`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/v3.0.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/IMvcBuilder.cs) implementation, which has a corresponding [`AddJsonOptions`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v3.0.0/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/MvcCoreMvcBuilderExtensions.cs#L51) extension method. The new-style methods  `AddControllers`, `AddControllersWithViews`, and `AddRazorPages` also return an `IMvcBuilder` implementation. Chain with these in the same way you would chain with `AddMvc`:

```
services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        // ...
    });
```

Note that `options` here is no longer for Json.NET, but for the newer `System.Text.Json` APIs. If you still want to use Json.NET, see [tymtam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392090/2630078)

Comment: Adding "options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;" had no effect

Comment: To others who hit this page looking for Enum conversion:

    [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonStringEnumConverter))]
    public enum SomeEnum

Comment: For ASP.NET Core 3.1 (May/2021), we can specify the following to ask the JSON serializer not not serialize null values via the startup.cs file:                                                               services.AddControllers()
                .AddJsonOptions(options => options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true);

Answer (score 76):

## Option A. AddControllers

This is still MVC, and requires Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson nuget package, but you said you use `AddControllers`.

From [Add Newtonsoft.Json-based JSON format support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/advanced/formatting?view=aspnetcore-3.0#add-newtonsoftjson-based-json-format-support)

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    // Use the default property (Pascal) casing
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();

    // Configure a custom converter
    options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new MyCustomJsonConverter());
});
```

---

## Option B. DefaultSettings

`JsonConvert.DefaultSettings = () => new JsonSerializerSettings (...)`

[JsonConvert.DefaultSettings Property](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DefaultSettings.htm)

> Gets or sets a function that creates default JsonSerializerSettings. Default settings are automatically used by serialization methods on JsonConvert, and ToObject () and FromObject(Object) on JToken. To serialize without using any default settings create a JsonSerializer with Create().

Comment: Hi, this sets settings on Json.NET level, how can it be done on ASP.NET level?

Comment: It configures the settings on ASP.NET level, meaning default ModelBinding now happens using NewtonsoftJson serializer.

Comment: Thank you, Option A worked for me. Upgraded from 2.2 to 3.1 and my endpoint broke because `System.Text.Json` doesn't handle polymorphism or enums properly. Nice easy way to change the default serializer.

Comment: Example for ignroing null values and converting enums to strings:

`services.AddControllersWithViews().AddNewtonsoftJson(o =>
{
  o.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
  o.SerializerSettings.Converters.Add(new Newtonsoft.Json.Converters.StringEnumConverter()); 
});`

Comment: Not sure I'd do this on a new project, but moving legacy code to a new version...  +1 for the `AddNewtonsoftJson()` and the link to the docs.

Answer (score 47):

Adding Newtonsoft is not necessary, quite a problems with adding Newtonsoft compatibility packages on .Net Core 3.0 project.

See also https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/13564

Of course, one would celebrate property naming `PascalCase`, NA at the moment...
So `null` for `PropertyNamingPolicy` means PascalCase, which is obviously not very good.

```
// Pascal casing
services.AddControllersWithViews().
        AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        });
```

Comment: Thank you @OSP, but what do you exactly mean "obviously not very good"?

Answer (score 12):

You can try `System.Text.Json`, the newly released Json nuget package converter.
Startup.cs as below
You can write this code inside the configirationSetting method.

```
 services.AddControllers()
     .AddJsonOptions(options =>
      {
          options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
          options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
          options.JsonSerializerOptions.Converters.Add (new JsonStringEnumConverter ());
      });
```

Comment: 1. Not so newly 2.Can you please explain claim _"Newtonsoft no longer works very well in .Net Core"_? 3. what is _"configirationSetting method"_ ?

Comment: Hello @GuruStron, 1) it is newly, beacuse it is **net core 3.1** libary supported. (https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/try-the-new-system-text-json-apis/) 2) (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0 ) 3) Microsoft is now using new nuget packages from its own freamwork in all software.
For this reason, it withdraws support from many of them and directs them to their own packages.
**Newtonsoft.Json** provides support, but now **Microsoft** wants its own package for Core.

Comment: 1) Article you've linked in this point is around 1.5 years old 2) this one is about HOW to migrate and does not explain claim in question =)) 3) this point does not answer question _"what is "configirationSetting method""_ =)

Comment: Even in 2022 System.Text.Json is missing core flexibility features  that make is a far from ideal candidate for JSON serialization. JSON is designed to be greedy in operation, System.Text.Json continually fails to match that requirement.

Comment: Software is an ever-evolving and greedy thing. The compenent that has met the needs for a few years now does not. That's why the software is constantly evolving. Lots of new programming languages ​​are coming out, requirements are changing.I said Microsoft's suggestion and now Microsoft offers its own add-ons and does not recommend 3-part add-ons.  Currently net core works very stable with Microsoft's plugins.

Comment: I also added "options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;" for similar behavior to .NET framework.

Answer (score 5):

In **.net6** add this code after **.AddControllers()** in **program.cs** file:

```
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
});
```

Comment: Question is about net 3.1

Comment: My app has the old `WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)` left, which does not have `.Services`. How do I set the JsonOptions there?

Comment: Add it after AddControllers() methos in Startup.cs file.

Answer (score 3):

**1.install NuGet :
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson
or**

```
   <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.2" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

**2. Add Startup.cs :**

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
     {
         //JSON Serializer
         services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
           {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = 
               Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
           });
    }
```