# JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core-3.1, system.text.json

Consider the code...

```
using System;
using System.Text.Json;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        int id = 9;
        string str = "{\"id\": " + id + "}";
        var u = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(str);
        Console.WriteLine($"User ID: {u.Id}, Correct: {id == u.Id}");  // always 0/init/default value
    }
}


public class User {
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Why isn't the data being deserialized properly into the `User` object?  I also verified the behavior via [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uxY6p5) in case it was an issue local to my system.  No exception is thrown.

My actual implementation is read from an `[ApiController]`'s `[HttpPost]` action after I `return Created("user", newUser)`.  It is called in my MVC/Razor project via `_httpClient.PostAsync`.  I verified the values are correct when `Created` is returned to the `PostAsync` call, but no matter what, the value parsed from the response body contains only default values (the actual ID is a `Guid`).

I initially thought it might have been an UTF8 related issue, as that is the encoding for the `StringContent` I post to the `ApiController`.  UTF8 deserialization is referenced [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to#deserialize-from-utf-8), but I had trouble getting from the IO.Stream of the `HttpContent` to a `ReadOnlySpan` or `Utf8JsonReader`.

I found [this project](https://github.com/GillCleeren/BethanysPieShopHR/blob/04c7367958b5c46f84e3658ee3a0b95a293e9cbb/BethanysPieShopHRM.Server/Services/EmployeeDataService.cs#L40) while searching, which makes me think it should work as I expected.

Comment: It is always a good idea to serialize a sample first to see a sample. I did it and found out that it was looking for `Id` instead of `id` it couldn't find it so it takes the default value `0`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Your problem is that `System.Text.Json` is case-sensitive by default, so `"id": 9` (all lowercase) is not mapped to the `Id` property.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?view=netcore-3.1#case-insensitive-property-matching):

> **Case-insensitive property matching**
>
> By default, deserialization looks for case-sensitive property name matches between JSON and the target object properties. To change that behavior, set [`JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-character-casing) to `true`:
>
> **Note: The [web default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-configure-options#web-defaults-for-jsonserializeroptions) is case-insensitive.**
>
> ```
> var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
> {
>    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
> };
> var weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WeatherForecast>(jsonString, options);
> ```

So you need to do that also:

```
var u = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(str, new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true });
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4X0DI4).

(If the difference is entirely due to camel casing and not more general differences in case, you can instead configure the serializer to use camel case as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60123509/3744182) by [t.j.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3246805/t-j).)

You can configure the option on startup in ASP.NET Core 3.0 as shown in *[How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58392039/3744182)*:

```
services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

Alternatively you could apply [`[JsonPropertyName("id")]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.1) to your model:

```
public class User {
    [JsonPropertyName("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Fozf0u).

Comment: correct, plus extra useful info regarding config... marking as solution

Comment: If you expect all properties in the JSON to be camel-cased instead, an alternative to using `PropertyNameCaseInsensitive` is to set the `PropertyNamingPolicy` to `CamelCase` explicitly and leave the comparison as the default/case-sensitive.

Comment: Using `JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase` is generally more performant (with case sensitive comparison) compared to opting for case insensitive comparison. Otherwise, setting both, like asp.net core does, works as well.

Comment: in startup this should be like this or will give error options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;

Comment: I've lost 3 hours trying to understand why it doesn't work, and it was all for case sensitivity . Thanks man

Comment: In my case i removed getter and setters if that help anyone! cheers

Comment: So, I'm an idiot. I had this same problem but turns out I had `private set` on the properties I was trying to update while attempting deserialization from a different class!

Comment: Thank you for this. This should have been part of the library logic. Also, the last answer in this post with the JsonPropertyName attributes was required for me since a lot of my Json property names were split with an underscore like "first_name" and wouldn't map to my class property of FirstName - otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [mr5](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304737/mr5) who [suggested it was a casing issue via chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/48537821#48537821).

Changing the string to use TitleCase ("Id") solves the issue.

I was in the process of submitting a ticket, and one of the [possibly related issues](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29577) [comments](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29577#issuecomment-504032913) lead me to [another issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/29063), which lead to the documentation, which has a [solution](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Text.Json/docs/SerializerProgrammingModel.md#property-name-feature)

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
```

Using the options, solves the problem...

```
string str = "{\"id\": " + id + "}";
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
var u = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<User>(str, options);
```

Leaving this all up in case it helps someone else.

Comment: The doc pages might be helpful as well. 
Specifically https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-migrate-from-newtonsoft-how-to#case-insensitive-deserialization

Regarding the discussion from the chat (quoted here: "weird that it isnt an issue elsewhere ([FromBody] handles it just fine"), that's because of the default options are configured differently within aspnet: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/a6bc6ce23dad5a9d02596cf2e91e3c4f965c61bc/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/JsonOptions.cs#L15-L29

Answer (score 1):

You can also read this microsoft documentation [JSON Serialization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0), for the configuration you can use the following:

```
JsonSerializerOptions _jsonOptions = new(JsonSerializerDefaults.Web);
var serialized = JsonSerializer.Serialize(data, _jsonOptions);
var deserialized = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TEntity>(serialized , _jsonOptions);
```

**JsonSerializerDefaults.Web** it is a predefined enum setting like "camelCase value", "case-insensitive property names", etc, check this [JsonSerializerDefaults.?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializerdefaults?view=net-5.0#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerDefaults_Web)
, if you want to customize you would check the documentation again [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-configure-options?pivots=dotnet-5-0)

Answer (score -1):

In `ConfigureServices` at `Startup.cs`

```
services.AddControllers()
        .AddJsonOptions(o => {
            o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy=JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
            o.PropertyNameCasInsensitive=true
        });
```

Comment: PropertyNameCasInsensitive has a typo and isn't found directly in o but rather in JsonSerializerOptions so it should be o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive