# Select part of json with System.text.json

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I begin c# and Deserialize Json. In my training I studied Newtonsoft, but I would like to do the same with system.text.json

With this json, I want to select

- searchedProducts > featuredProduct
  AND
- searchedProducts > productDetails

To make a object list.

```
https://api.nvidia.partners/edge/product/search?page=1&limit=9&locale=fr-fr&category=GPU&gpu=RTX%203090,RTX%203080%20Ti,RTX%203080,RTX%203070%20Ti,RTX%203070,RTX%203060%20Ti,RTX%203060&gpu_filter=RTX%203090~12,RTX%203080%20Ti~7,RTX%203080~16,RTX%203070%20Ti~3,RTX%203070~18,RTX%203060%20Ti~8,RTX%203060~2,RTX%202080%20SUPER~1,RTX%202080~0,RTX%202070%20SUPER~0,RTX%202070~0,RTX%202060~6,GTX%201660%20Ti~0,GTX%201660%20SUPER~9,GTX%201660~8,GTX%201650%20Ti~0,GTX%201650%20SUPER~3,GTX%201650~17
```

> Class

```
public class CarteGraphique
{
    public string displayName { get; set; }
    public string prdStatus { get; set; }
    public List<Retailer> retailers { get; set; }
}
```

With Newtonsoft, I do the following:

> Newtonsoft

```
JObject jsonParse = JObject.Parse(json);

IList<CarteGraphique> products = new List<CarteGraphique>();

IList<JToken> productDetailsParse = jsonParse["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"]
    .Children()
    .Where(n => n["isFounderEdition"].Value<bool>() == true)
    .ToList();
var featuredProductParse = jsonParse["searchedProducts"]["featuredProduct"];


foreach (JToken item in productDetailsParse)
{
    CarteGraphique result = item.ToObject<CarteGraphique>();
    products.Add(result);
}
var featuredProduct = featuredProductParse.ToObject<CarteGraphique>();

products.Add(featuredProduct);



foreach (var item in products)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.DisplayName);
}
```

I want to do that with System.Text.Json...but I don't know how select json part "productDetails" for add this in a object list.

> System.text.json

```
var listGpu = new List<CarteGraphique>();

var jsonParse = JsonDocument.Parse(json);

var jsonFilter = jsonParse.RootElement
    .GetProperty("searchedProducts")
    .GetProperty("featuredProduct")
    .GetRawText();

var jsonObj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<CarteGraphique>(jsonFilter);

listGpu.Add(jsonObj);


foreach (var item in listGpu)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.displayName);
}
```

Can you help me please?
Documentation is not clear for the beginner that i am.

Comment: `System.Text.Json` is case-sensitive so you need to use `new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMaXSh. and [JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60123515/3744182).  This is why `CarteGraphique.PrdStatus` is not deserialized successfully.  Is that your only problem?  It's not clear where you problem is exactly, from your question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry bad paste, i edit my class. No it's not that, i just want get "productDetails" and deserialize for add in a list, like my example with Newtonsoft

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can emulate the Json.NET logic as follows:

```
using var jsonParse = JsonDocument.Parse(json); // Be sure to dispose the JsonDocument!

var options = new JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true };

var products = jsonParse.RootElement
    .GetProperty("searchedProducts") // Get the searchedProducts value
    .GetProperty("productDetails")   // Get the productDetails value
    .EnumerateArray()                // Enumerate its items
    .Where(n => n.GetProperty("isFounderEdition").GetBoolean()) // Filter on those for which isFounderEdition == true
    .Select(n => n.ToObject<CarteGraphique>(options)) // Deserialize to a CarteGraphique
    .ToList();
    
// Add the searchedProducts.featuredProduct item to the list.
var featuredProduct = jsonParse.RootElement
    .GetProperty("searchedProducts")
    .GetProperty("featuredProduct")
    .ToObject<CarteGraphique>(options);

products.Add(featuredProduct);
```

Where `ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)` is an extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc) to *[System.Text.Json.JsonElement ToObject workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58138793/3744182)*:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonElement element, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        var bufferWriter = new System.Buffers.ArrayBufferWriter<byte>();
        using (var writer = new Utf8JsonWriter(bufferWriter))
            element.WriteTo(writer);
        return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(bufferWriter.WrittenSpan, options);
    }

    public static T ToObject<T>(this JsonDocument document, JsonSerializerOptions options = null)
    {
        if (document == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(document));
        return document.RootElement.ToObject<T>(options);
    }       
}
```

Notes:

- [`JsonDocument`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsondocument?view=net-5.0) is disposable.  Failure to dispose of it will *result in the memory not being returned to the pool, which will increase GC impact across various parts of the framework*, according to the docs.
- In .NET 6.0 Microsoft plans to implement direct deserialization from a `JsonElement`, see *[We should be able serialize and deserialize from DOM #31274](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31274)*.  In the meantime the above extension  method can be used.
- I did not add any checking for missing properties.  If properties might be missing, use [`JsonElement.TryGetProperty()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonelement.trygetproperty?view=net-5.0).  See *[Getting nested properties with System.Text.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553962/3744182)* for some extension methods that can make that easier.
- Unlike Json.NET, System.Text.Json is case-sensitive by default.  To enable case-insensitive deserialization use `JsonSerializerOptions { PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true }` as shown in *[JsonSerializer.Deserialize fails](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60123376/3744182)*.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMaXSh).

Comment: Thank, It helps me a lot, it's very good to explain. Just a question, why use "using" on parse and webclient on your demo ?

Comment: @Castiel - because both are disposable.  `JsonDocument` needs to be disposed as explained in my answer's "Notes".  The older `WebClient` (which I used in the fiddle because it's synchronous) also should be disposed.  However, the newer `HttpClient` should be cached and reused not disposed, see [Do HttpClient and HttpClientHandler have to be disposed between requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15705092/3744182).

Answer (score 1):

I also have faced the same inconvinieces when moved to JsonDocument. So I have developed a small library to re-create the same behavior JObject had. It allows to navigate domain object model using indexer-like syntax. It is called JsonEasyNavigation, you can find it on [github](https://github.com/sharkadi-a/JsonEasyNavigation) or get from [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonEasyNavigation/).

In your case, the solution could be the following:

```
List<CarteGraphique> products = new List<CarteGraphique>();

using var jsonDocument = JsonDocument.Parse(json);
var nav = jsonDocument.ToNavigation();

var productDetails = nav["searchedProducts"]["productDetails"].Values
    .Where(x => x["isFounderEdition"].GetBooleanOrDefault())
    .Select(x => x.Map<CarteGraphique>())
    .ToArray();

var featuredProduct = nav["searchedProducts"]["featuredProduct"].Map<CarteGraphique>();

products.AddRange(productDetails);
products.Add(featuredProduct);
```

JsonDocument have to be transformed into the JsonNavigationElement using **ToNavigation()** method. I hope you will find it useful.