# Setting json serializer settings in startup netcoreapp 3.1

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-core-3.1

Hey all how do i correctly update my json SerializerSettings in my netcoreapp 3.1 application? Im trying to update this setting in the startup.cs I've tried to set this two ways, by using `AddController()` and also `AddMvc()`

```
        builder.Services
            .AddControllers()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true; })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });

        builder.Services
            .AddMvc()
            .AddJsonOptions(options => { options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true; })
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            });
```

I don't think it's being applied correctly as I've tried to create unit tests by adding some null values to my JSON file however null reference exceptions are still being thrown, I tried to create a `var json = new JsonSerializer()` so i could view the serializer settings and i could still see the NullValueHandling = Included.

Comment: You're asking multiple questions here, but generally you should have [one question per post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/275908).  Note that `AddNewtonsoftJson()` only configures the `JsonSerializerSettings` **used by ASP.NET Core**.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58392090) to [How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58392039) and also [JsonConvert.DefaultSettings](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/p_newtonsoft_json_jsonconvert_defaultsettings.htm).

Comment: apologies ill edit the question

Comment: Can you share your sample code?