# System.Text.Json Custom Deserialization for Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, StringCollection>>>

Tags: c#, system.text.json

I need to have the `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer` be able to deserialize this nested Dictionary type structure, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Text.Json.JsonElement' to type 'System.String'.
```

I have the following JSON

```
{
  "ACL": {
    "granted": {
      "Business": {
        "Delete": [
          "Customer1",
          "Customer2"
        ]
      },
      "Account": {
        "Create": [
          "Customer1",
          "Customer3"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Going into the following model

```
using System.Collections.Specialized;
public record AclRecord 
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, StringCollection>>> ACL { get; set; }
}
```

What would a JsonConverter to deserialize this type of triple nested Dictionary type structure look like?

Comment: Use var acl=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AclRecord>(json); and forget about system.text.json forever

Comment: @Serge I don't have that option.  There is an underlying service using System.Text.Json, so I need a converter to make it work.

Comment: Then create a custom converter. You dont have any choice. System.Text.Json works only for a very simple cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use `List<string>` instead of `StringCollection` for your deserialization target, this will work out of the box:

```
public record AclRecord
{
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, List<string>>>> ACL { get; set; }
}

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AclRecord>(json);
```

If you MUST use `StringCollection`, you will need to write a custom converter.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `StringCollection` with `List<string>` as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347656/3744182) by [David L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1165998/david-l) is the best solution to your problem, as `StringCollection` is an untyped collection from .Net 1.1 and typed collections should always be preferred over untyped collections.

That being said, if you must deserialize a `StringCollection` with System.Text.Json (e.g. because you are working with a legacy class you cannot rewrite), you may do so with the following simple [`JsonConverter<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1):

```
public class StringCollectionConverter : JsonConverter<StringCollection>
{
    public override StringCollection? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(ref reader, options)?.Aggregate(new StringCollection(), (sc, s) => { sc.Add(s); return sc; });
    
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, StringCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, value.Cast<string>(), options);
}
```

If your `StringCollection` is large and you would like to avoid an intermediate `List<String>`, modify `Read()` as follows:

```
public override StringCollection? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
        throw new JsonException();
    var sc = new StringCollection();
    while (reader.Read() && reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        sc.Add(reader.GetString());
    return sc;
}
```

Then add the converter to `JsonSerializerOptions` and deserialize as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions 
{ 
    Converters = { new StringCollectionConverter(), /* Add other converters here */ },
    // Set other options below
    WriteIndented = true,
};
var model = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<AclRecord>(json, options);
```

To configure the options for Asp.NET Core 3.1 and later, see *[How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58392039/3744182)*.

Demo fiddles [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/myhWp8) and [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/w7Ygh5).