# How to read camelCase JSON request from http body?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-7.0, payload, camelcasing, pascalcasing

I have following API endpoint

```
public class CreateSupplierCommand
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    public string? Website { get; set; }
}
    
[ApiController]
public class SuppliersController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...

    [HttpPost, Route("api/supplier")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] CreateSupplierCommand command)
    {
        var supplier = new Supplier(command.Name, command.Website);
        _context.Suppliers.Add(supplier);
        _context.SaveChanges();
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

and the following request payload with PascalCase works. The endpoint is called and supplier is created.

```
{Name: "foo", Website: "bar"}
```

but camelCase attributes does not. The endpoint is not even called

```
{name: "foo", website: "bar"}
```

I am not sure, but I think in .NET6 it worked. Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that following code in **Program.cs** fix the issue

```
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
});
```

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59237265/2333663)