# Add JsonConverter on Class without compilator attribute

Tags: c#, json, serialization, system.text.json

I have a class `ClientMessage` with many derived class.
I created a custom `ClientMessageConverter` with System.Text.Json.Serialization.

Is there a way to  always use this converter on this class, as if i had `[JsonConverter(typeof(ClientMessageConverter))]`
(I imported ClientMessage from a compiled assembly, so i cannot add a attribute on the class)

And ideally i would like to be exempt of creating JsonSerializerOptions everywhere in my code.

Comment: [Register a custom converter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#register-a-custom-converter)

Comment: @shingo is exactly right. Also, the term you are looking for is **attribute**, not **decorator**.

Comment: System.Text.Json doesn't support global JsonSerializerOptions, see [How to globally set default options for System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58331479).  So if you don't want to use JsonSerializerOptions everywhere in your code you will need to use one of the workarounds suggested in answers to that question.  Alternatively some higher level framework you are using will have default options, see e.g. [How to set json serializer settings in asp.net core 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58392039).